# Finding all documents that don't have a relations with others in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of Users and one of Posts. I want to find all the posts that one user has not viewed yet. I expect the number of posts one user views to grow over time, possibly reaching tens or hundreds of thousands for some users, although the majority of users will only have a few hundreds.

How should I organize my data in a MongoDB database?
Should I keep the array of viewed posts in the User collection, in the Post collection, in a collection on its own (a document per view) or what else?

How should I then query the database?

Comment: I think you need to define better what kind of queries you're gonna end up doing most of the time. or what kind of queries are important to you to have good performance in, Once these questions are answered it's going to be easier to decide on an architecture.

Comment: I only asked about one query that I want to optimize for. The users of my app will see a list of posts whenever they access the app. They can swipe those posts away and I want  them to not appear again. The main query I need to perform is fetching a set of posts to show that the user hasn't seen/swiped yet. They should be sorted by the date of the last comment and possibly by a score assigned depending on keywords/tags selected by the user. I'm wondering how to set up the database to filter out posts the user has already seen.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be constructable using the aggregation pipeline. First `$lookup` to join posts to post views, then `$match` with `$exists: false` to remove existing posts.

This won't be a cheap query with a large volume of data. One strategy for making it faster is by limiting, for example, the time allowed for posts prior to the join, or scoping the posts to a forum/tag, etc.